# I encountered a mistake: Couldn't register this node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

This is my configuration file config.json

and I run on the command line：

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeconfig.json
```

But I encountered such a mistake and I can not find the answer:

```
21:27:48.334 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not respondi
ng: Connect to localhost:4444 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] f
ailed: Connection refused: connect
```

I do not understand why this is so?

Comment: Why do you tag this with Python when it is java?

Comment: Have you made sure you have started the hub using the command "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role hub" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly states that the node is not finding the hub running on your localhost listening on port 4444.
As Krishnan mentioned above, you need to start your hub first using the command

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role hub`

This command will start your hub on localhost and by default uses 4444 port.